# Change width of drawer in MDL

Tags: css, html, material-design, material-design-lite

I've just got started with Material Design Lite. I want to change the width of the drawer.

What I have tried is something along these lines:

```
.mdl-layout__drawer {
  width: 25%;
}
```

This results in the drawer overlapping the content area.

How do I correct this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The drawer is an absolute component that rest in it's parent container a defined left position. When you change it's width, you'll need to alter it's position too.

Here's the css only solution for a width of 500px -

```
.mdl-layout__drawer {
  width: 500px;
  left: -250px;
}

.mdl-layout__drawer.is-visible {
  left: 0;
}
```

Here's a codepen example -http://codepen.io/mdlhut/pen/pJmjBe